# Getting the API error response from CycleJS HTTPDriver

Tags: cyclejs, xstream-js

I'm trying out CycleJS with xstream and I can't find a way to both rescue an error (e.g. 422) and get the JSON response from the HTTP driver.

To rescue from an error, I'm using xstream's `replaceError` which seems to work like this:

```
sources.HTTP
  .select('hello')
  .map((response$) =>
    // No response$.body or response$.error, just response$.request.
    response$.replaceError(() => xs.of(errorObject))
  ).flatten()
```

However, the API returns an error message that I would like to display to the user, and it is lost if replaced with a default object. The only property on the `response$` that's set is the actual request data.

Versions:

```
"@cycle/dom": "^12.2.5"
"@cycle/http": "^11.0.1"
"@cycle/xstream-run": "^3.1.0"
"xstream": "^6.4.0"
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to catch the error object `err` in the argument for `replaceError` (you weren't using it):

```
response$.replaceError(err => /* use err here */)
```

Comment: Had no idea you get this in the `replaceError` callback, thanks!